# How to copy column from one sheet to another if the condition is met in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to work this out for a while. How can I copy certain column from one sheet to another if the first cell with value in that column is for example "Cell". My guesses are false but maybe it will be helpful to better understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
 for i=5 to lcol
   if Sheet8(6,i).value ="Cell" then
     Sheet8.Range(6,i).Copy Destination:=Sheet7.Range("M3:N" & lRow)
   end if
 next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your copy statement from:

```
Sheet8.Range(6,i).Copy Destination:=Sheet7.Range("M3:N" & lRow)
```

To:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8").Range(6, i).EntireColumn.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("M3")
```

Comment: It's giving me an error "1004". Application-defined or object-defined error.